# Join two files based on a matching column, but preserve non-matching lines?

Tags: bash, join

I have two text files that I would like to join based upon matches in the second column. File1 is larger than file2, containing matches for all entries in file2, plus many non-matches.

Join works, and the output file joined the matching entries as expected. However, I would like to preserve the non-matching entries in file1, such that they still appear in the output file.

Both files are tab-delimited. File1 has 13 columns, and file2 has 4. I am matching between column 2 of file1 and column 1 of file2.

How can I do this such that the non-matching lines from file1 still appear in the output file (file3)?

I have been using the following code (bash):

```
join -t $'\t' -1 2 -2 1 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,1.10,1.11,1.12,1.13,2.2,2.3,2.4 <(sort -k2,2 file1)  <(sort -k1,1 file2) > file3
```

Thanks in advance for your help, I really appreciate it! Apologies for a novice question, I am a biologist who is attempting to improve his computational proficiency, and the learning curve has been steep.

Regards,

Anthony

Comment: Please post sample data from both files along with your desired output.

Answer (score 5):

From `man join`:

```
-a file_number  
  In addition to the default output, produce a line for each unpairable line in file file_number.
```

This seems to be exactly what you want.
So since you want the lines from file1 to also appear in the output, add `-a 1` in your command.

```
join -a 1 -t $'\t' -1 2 -2 1 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,1.10,1.11,1.12,1.13,2.2,2.3,2.4 <(sort -k2,2 file1)  <(sort -k1,1 file2) > file3
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. I had read the man file, but I was being particularly dense.

Comment: @anth please accept the answer, to facilitate recognizing that this is a solution.